# Multiple copies in a single page of crystal Report using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to print multiple copies(2) of a same report in a single page (top and bottom) of crystal report using c#..

Can any one help me with this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your fields twice if they are fixed, otherwise create subreport and put it twice on a page.